# What is the meaning of the value of the boosted tree?

Tags: graphviz, decision-tree, xgboost

I plotted a tree and in the end of the trees (in the leaves) there are shown some values. What do they mean?

```
# model parameters
colsample_bytree = 0.4
objective = 'binary:logistic'
learning_rate = 0.05
eval_metric = 'auc'
max_depth = 8
min_child_weight = 4
n_estimators = 5000
seed = 7

# create and train model
bst = xgb.train(param, 
                dtrain, 
                num_boost_round = best_iteration)

dot = xgb.to_graphviz(bst, rankdir='LR')
dot.render("trees1")
```

I thought, it is a predicted proba score, but the leaves' values' range is up to .01. Whereas predicted proba score' range is up to 1. May be, it means predicted proba' score divided by 10 (e.g. leaf value = 0.01 means that predicted proba = 0.1)?

And why do some leaves have negative values (e.g. -0.01)?
Thank you.

[image: Part of the tree]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of a leaf is your "eval_metric", local to your split :). For you it is the AUC.

Here are all attributes of a tree :

```
n_nodes = estimator.tree_.node_count
children_left = estimator.tree_.children_left
children_right = estimator.tree_.children_right
feature = estimator.tree_.feature
threshold = estimator.tree_.threshold
```

From doc : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py

Can't find it in the doc but "tree_.impurity" does exist aswell.

Comment: Gwendal, I've tried to change auc-metric to log-loss and the others. The values in the leaf-nodes - are equal. I tried to learn documentation, but didn't find, how to understand - what class is predicted in the end of the tree or what probability is predicted? Will be gratefull for help.

Comment: Each end leaf is a part of the initial population, assigned to a single result. This field match all branches splits, and means that every new data that once again match theses splits will get the same value.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNZ8q.jpg

Here is a good exemple, every end node, leaf, contains a class attributes, which is the population assigned result

Comment: Gwendal, thank you. Do I understand you right, that every leaf is a part of the whole population. This means, that all leaf values in summa will give - 1? In the chart you linked in the comment, there are predicted classes in each leaf. How can I add predicted classes to each leaf?

Comment: In my picture exemple. All leaf sample is equal to first leaf sample. About your values, since you metric is AUC. I guess it is the AUC of the leaf population, meaning the perf of your model for the given sample. Nothing to do with the predicted value :). Needs to be checked in documentation.

Comment: Gwendal, thank you. I noted in your picture, that all the leaves from the left (except 1 node) - are benign classes and those are from the right - are malignant. May be, my tree has the same distribution, but I'm not sure. Concerning AUC, I would like to beleive, that on the end of the leaf - is the AUC metric for a given sample, but: 1) nothing has changed in the leaf values since I changed AUC to the other metrics 2) it seems to me, that this metric doesn't have any useful information. I learnt documentation via your link and xgboost.to_graphviz - documentation. I'm still stuck. (

Comment: I think I'm at the end of my understanding of trees representation here. I could be giving wrongs insights :s 
Sorry Alex